# Tabulator Calculations For Multiple Groups

Tags: tabulator

When grouping by multiple columns using the following function:

```
groupBy:['column_one','column_two'],
columnCalcs:"Both"
```

What I am hoping for is a total for each group (and sub group), as well as the grand total at the very bottom of the screen.

Currently, only the last defined group (column two in the above scenario) and the grand total show. I do not receive a total, per group level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im afraid that it is not possible to configure the table in that way at present, you can either have calculations in the child groups or the table as a whole but nothing in between